# splash screen contain video in flutter

Tags: flutter, video, splash-screen

I am trying to add 3 second video in splash screen in FLUTTER. so how to remove white screen before splash screen while launcher screen or any other suggestion are welcome for this.

Here's what I've tried

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
late VideoPlayerController _controller;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/video.mp4");
  _controller.addListener(() {
    if (!_controller.value.isPlaying &&
        _controller.value.position.inSeconds >=
            _controller.value.duration.inSeconds) {
      // completion
      _controller.dispose();
      Get.offAll(() => FirstScreen());
    }
  });
  controller.initialize().then(() => setState(() {}));
  _controller.play();
}
@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);

  return GetMaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home:  Scaffold(
      body: VideoPlayer(_controller),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Try using flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16 package - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Answer (score 1):

You can't entirely **remove** this screen. Only thing you can do is altering it in some way that it matches your video playing screen. Use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash package and make it like that user doesn't feel screen changing(make background same, etc)

Comment: sorry..!! no luck with this package.

Comment: please specify what is the issue you are facing exactly. It is not about luck.

Comment: this package allows image not video. I want video as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please, understand one thing. You never ever can remove this page. So just get the image of video and make a page with that package with the image. Then when it finishes load it passes to the splash screen with actual video. The purpose here is remove white or black empty screen, user need to wait anyway. In release mode it takes less than a second.

Comment: You can't put the video on that splash screen, provided by Android and iOS. It is necessary to pass, but not free to do anything

Answer (score 0):

First create `styles.xml` file inside `android/app/src/main/res/values`.

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a Drawable splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.  -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now add your splash screen inside `res/drawable` folder.

AndroidManifest.xml

Inside `activity` tag create `meta-data` like this,

```
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame" android:resource="@drawable/splash_screen" />
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
```

Comment: this will help for image only, I want video.

Comment: oh! I haven't try with video but it works fine in splash image .